# linux redhat + hung + reason for hung

Tags: linux, redhat, logging

I have linux redhat machine - 6.8

and from the /var/log/message file I see the following lines:

from my point is seems that linux is hung because the bad connection to the server - 100.1.93.7 ,

is it correct ?

```
 Oct 30 04:39:40  guard_tap[18038]: Delayed server connection to 100.1.93.7 error: Connection timed out
 Oct 30 04:40:31  kernel: INFO: task oracle:16131 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
 Oct 30 04:40:31  kernel:      Tainted: G        W  -- ------------    2.6.32-642.4.2.el6.x86_64 #1
 Oct 30 04:40:31  kernel: "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
 Oct 30 04:40:31  kernel: oracle        D 0000000000000001     0 16131      1 0x00000000
 Oct 30 04:40:31  kernel: ffff8801012a7a98 0000000000000082 ffff8801012a79e8 ffffffffa03093ee
 Oct 30 04:40:31  kernel: ffff8801012a7a18 ffffffffa0309c90 ffff880700b057c0 ffff8801012a7a48
 Oct 30 04:40:31  kernel: ffff880700b05870 ffff88082ba2e448 ffff88010c6e3ad8 ffff8801012a7fd8
 Oct 30 04:40:31  kernel: Call Trace:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be just coincidence
Your real issue is this

```
INFO: task oracle:16131 blocked for more than 120 seconds
```

So you should check your Oracle alert log file.

Comment: can you explain the meaning of INFO: task oracle:16131 ?  ( what is the number 16131 ? )

Comment: is this number is the number of the oracle proccess?

Comment: Yes, it's PID - Process ID